# fresh install, won't boot, only in safemode

Tags: boot, dual-boot

it's a win7 dual boot.
it just gives me the orange background when booting and nothing else.
in safe mode however it boots normal but very slow/freezes when i try to do anything.
i don't know how to go about it, when i live run it from usb it works like magic
and very fast, way faster than windows 7;

i have now deleted it, but i'am looking forward to making it work.
any help is appreciated, thanks in advance
here are my specs

```
    Operating System
        MS Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Core i5 750  @ 2.67GHz    44 °C
        Lynnfield 45nm Technology
    RAM
        4.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 660MHz (9-9-9-24)
    Motherboard
        Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. P55A-UD3 (Socket 1156)    37 °C
    Graphics
        E2241 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series (ATI) 43 °C
    Hard Drives
        488GB Seagate ST3500320AS ATA Device (SATA) 36 °C
    Optical Drives
        HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H62N ATA Device
    Audio
        Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install proprietary drivers if you can access System settings -> Additional Drivers. Then reboot.

Comment: hmm. thanks for the answer. i think i tried to download the driver for vga it downloaded it and didn't do anything after that.